# Doxygen including trailing slashes after one line @brief comment

Tags: doxygen

I'm documenting my code using long sets of slashes to make them stand out in the code.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// @brief This is a simple test struct.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct Foo
{
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /// @brief Function with single line brief to demonstrate issue.
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void a() {}
};
```

I've built doxygen from a fresh subversion checkout and when it's run on the code above the line of slashes at the end of each block are included in the brief description.  The problem doesn't exist in doxygen 1.8.1 that's installed on my system, so this appears to be a bug in the doxygen trunk.

I've submitted bug [700345](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700345) to the doxygen project, but am interested in taking a shot at fixing this myself.

I'm having trouble finding the code doxygen uses to detect the end of comment blocks.  Does anyone have experience working with this part of the code and have a moment to point me in the right direction?

FYI, a quick solution to this is to add a blank comment line after the @brief.  I'm not interested in going through ~100k lines of code to identify problematic comment blocks and add a blank line (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my proposed fix attached to the bug report you submitted.